# Insert into specific buffer (not the active buffer)?

Tags: buffers, insert

Is there any way to insert text into a buffer that *isn't* the active buffer with Elisp?

Perhaps there is an equivalent to `with-temp-buffer` that takes a specific, existing buffer as an argument?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Perhaps something like:

```
(with-current-buffer "*scratch*" (insert "Test"))
```

is what you want.

Comment: Of course! Don't know why I forgot that. Thank you.